# How to properly deliver events from the ViewModel?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components

I need some way to deliver events that should be done only once from the ViewModel. Currently, I'm using LiveData for this.
Use case:

I'm building some intent and then I should deliver it to fragment. The problem is obvious, after rotate, I get old data and startAtivity runs once again. 
I don't want to use some hacks with checks, etc. I'm sure there's should be the correct way to do such things.
The only way I've found is here: [link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) - SingleLiveEvent.

So, is it a correct way to do such things? 
What is the correct way to deliver UI dependent events from the ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Is it a correct way to do such things?**

Answer to this question is yes, if that does the job without leaking any objects at all than you've probably found right solution !.

---

> **What is the correct way to deliver UI dependent events from the
>   ViewModel?**

Above solution you've found out is okay in your use-case, but if you're finding a solution that don't involve `LiveData` at all than i might be able to point it to one direction. Check out a solution below :

- Let's say your `ViewModel` has a asynchronous method that you want to deliver result on UI.
- Take a interface object of your result type that provides interaction between your `ViewModel` & `Activity/Fragment`, on your async method from `ViewModel` pass your **`LifeCycleOwner object`** and **`interface object`** as method parameter.
- Now check in your method about your lifecycle events of your `LifecycleOwner` *(i.e. activity or fragment instance here)* and provide callback by interface on your UI.
- So, now you can mark your result as **null** once delivered to UI.

It's bit of setup, but will work when you want solution without `LiveData`.